# javascript Date.UTC return incorrect result

Tags: javascript

Hello i try get UTC datetime by Date.UTC method and got enexpected result with + 30 days; what is problem?

```
new Date(Date.UTC(2022, 12, 28, 11, 26, 0, 0))
// Sat Jan 28 2023 14:26:00
```

Comment: month index starts with 0

Comment: It's unclear what you are doing. You shouldn't mix UTC and local time. `use Date.UTC(2022, 12, 28, 11, 26, 0, 0).toUTCString()`

Comment: Always check [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) first if you encounter issues... _"`monthIndex` - An integer between 0 (January) and 11 (December) representing the month."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

second argument is `monthIndex` : Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for January to 11 for December.
You have to try:

`new Date(Date.UTC(2022, 11, 28, 11, 26, 0, 0))`

Comment: omg ... I couldn't even imagine such a thing...